# J2ME Mp3 player - playing mp3 files in loop

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

Hi any one knows how to play list of mp3 files in a loop automatically in J2ME? Please share code if u have...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to play an .mp3 or .wav file

```
Player p;
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(SoundName[sound]);
        try {
            p = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/X-wav");
            p.start();
            is.close();
            is = null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MediaException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

p.setLoopCount(100);//using this you can play the sound in loop
```